# Is there a way to to tell Latex to only print certain environment?

Tags: luatex, texstudio

my thesis is just about going to an end and I want to check all my equations, figures, etc.

Is there a way to choose a single environment just that latex ignores everything else? As an example, have all equations, recompile: have only figures, recompile: having plain text?

Thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: If in a hurry, you can have a look at the `comment`  package. It allows to print only parts of a document.

Comment: The `comment` package introduces a new environment to be either printed or ignored. So you have to manually go through the whole thesis to select and deselect the required portions. My guess is that OP is looking for a command that checks the environment compiling it when true and rejecting when not. Something like `check{equation}{true: compile}{false: reject}{next environment}`

Comment: The endfloat package can move any enviroment into a new file, which is normally printed at the end of the document.  See \DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor